# NoReverseMatch - Reverse for 'step-autocomplete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, autocomplete, view

First of all I realize this question has been asked several times prior, but I've looked at several solutions and have been unable to fix my issue. Furthermore, I have tried several things that have worked for me before when I've had this error, including using various 'return redirect/reverse/httpresponse' with arguments, and these haven't worked either. 
I'm following this tutorial https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst#id5 to create autocomplete fields, and in the second stage where I go into the shell and check if the url can be reversed I get the NoReverseMatch error. My view and url are below.
View:

```
class StepAutoComplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Step.objects.none()

        qs = Step.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

url:

```
from dal import autocomplete
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from buildpage import views
from .models import RouteStep, Step  
from .views import StepAutoComplete

app_name = 'Build Page'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^partrequestinfo/$', views.partrequestinfo, name='partrequestinfo'),
    url(r'^preparebuildlist/$', views.preparebuildlist, name='preparebuildlist'),
    url(r'^manufacturelist/$', views.manufacturelist, name='manufacturelist'),
    url(r'^preparebuildhome/$', views.preparebuildhome, name='preparebuildhome'),
    url(r'^step-autocomplete/$', StepAutoComplete.as_view(), name='step-autocomplete'),
    url(r'^partrequestprepare/$', views.partrequestprepare, name='partrequestprepare'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/confirmation$', views.partrequestdetail, name='partrequestdetail'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete$', views.partrequestdelete, name='partrequestdelete'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/manufacturebuild$', views.manufacturebuild, name='manufacturebuild'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/update$', views.preparebuildupdate, name='preparebuildupdate'),
]
```

traceback:

```
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 600, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 508, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'step-autocomplete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: Please show exactly where that URL is defined and whether it's being included by any other urlconfs.

Comment: does that help? added the rest of the urls.py

Comment: Not really; that can't possibly be the whole of the urls.py since urls need to live inside a `urlpatterns` list.

Comment: Apologies, one moment

Comment: There we go, whole urls.py

Comment: This looks like your top-level urls.py; you definitely shouldn't be defining an `app_name` there. Does it help if you remove that?

Comment: No difference, I've had that there for the entire time developing this app, removed it though

Comment: As of yet no luck, trying to fix it

Comment: Fixed it! I'm a fool, had to put the url into the main urls.py not the top level urls.py